# if statement for method in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to execute createRole() if RoleName is not set else the method EditRole()  but instead EditRole() execute for both whenever i click the button

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="selectedItem.RoleName? EditRole() : createRole()">Save Changes</button>
```

Comment: you should probably just call a method that then determines which method to call

Comment: I am sorry but you have not provided enough information here. What have you tried so far? What code do you have for your if statement? Please try and edit your post to provide us with as much information as possible so we can try and answer your question! Thanks!

Comment: @user3055606 your intent is correct maybe there is a default selected value for rolename please include the select control here. Rolename is always evaluated to true if selected item contains value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="save()">Save Changes</button>
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.save = function(){

    if($scope.selectedItem.RoleName){
        EditRole() 
    }
    else{
        createRole()
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better solution would be

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="check(selectedItem.RoleName)">Save Changes</button>

$scope.check=function(role){
if(role){ // exist
EditRole();
}
else{
createRole(); // if role name is not set
}
}
```